# Javascript throw 3 dice even spread

Tags: javascript

Simulate throwing 3 dice. Tried using

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
function dorand2(){
    document.getElementById("chng").innerHTML = '';
    var odice = document.getElementById("dice");

    var r1 = getRandomInt(1, 6);
    var r2 = getRandomInt(1, 6);
    var r3 = getRandomInt(1, 6);
    odice.innerHTML = "Dice A : " + r1 + " &nbsp;  &nbsp; Dice B : " + r2  + " &nbsp;  &nbsp; Dice C : " + r3;
}
```

Get same numbers for 1 or more in many tries. Am sure its even across runs. But looks odd, that out of 3 dice, get 5 on two of them, then next time 2 on two of them next turn... rarely are all 3 different. Would expect them to be different at least half the time?

Working sample:
http://sel2in.com/pages/prog/html/dice/

Comment: Don’t overcomplicate this. `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1` is all you need. Your code is working correctly, though, except that it’s possible to get a `7`.

Comment: Random doesn't mean all the numbers should be different. The chance of getting 1,2,3 is the same as getting 3,3,3 or 4,6,1 etc. etc.

Comment: Yes but its happening too often, i thought it was to do with the way random is implemented. I will try to make an automated sample with stats

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate it all you need is to use Math.floor(Math.random() *6+1
As shown here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function getRandInt() {
            document.getElementById("container1").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6+1); 
            document.getElementById("container2").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6+1);
            document.getElementById("container3").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6+1);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="getRandInt()">Throw</button>
    <p id="container1"></p>
    <br/>
    <p id="container2"></p>
    <br/>
    <p id="container3"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I started with something similar but like i said the incidence of same number appearing twice was high. Did you click it 10 times and see how many have doubles? since there are 6 different numbers 1-6, taking 3 at a time...expected fewer chances with same number. in fact use two static instances if java.util.Random get better spread (command line app)

Comment: That’s going to happen though having random numbers doesn’t mean they are going to be all different

Comment: I know talking about how often its happening.